# How to transfer non-native token on NEAR blockchain

Tags: transactions, token, action, transfer, nearprotocol

I'm struggling to transfer token with tokenAddress "meta-token.near" from wallet A to wallet B. I can't provide you with one of my solutions, cause the all don't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

So to create a transaction of transfer of NEAR I used this:
`transaction = nearAPI.transactions.createTransaction( from, publicKey, to, nonce, actions, recentBlockHash );`

I guess to transfer meta-token.near I need to do make specific actions. I tried to implement functionCall but failed.

UPDATE:

If I send tokens right from wallet, two methods get called:
https://nearscan.org/transactions/GTPxHnazxwH5hNzsMhd9WKe1GHEjecpkJowUzqKoitWr
https://nearscan.org/transactions/55bxoftL7fvnTw4Vth61SYp9BKoBTinkESXGUscR6xwa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

```js
const actions3 = [
  nearAPI.transactions.functionCall(
    "storage_deposit",
    Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ "account_id": to })),
    MAX_GAS,
    deposit
  ),
  nearAPI.transactions.functionCall(
    "ft_transfer", 
    Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ "receiver_id": to, "amount": amount })),
    MAX_GAS,
    1
  )
];
```